# Dismissed when probation period ended and notice period expired

Tags: contracts, probation, rights

I just started to work on a company the 4th of April. My probation was supported to end the 4th July. In my contract, as I can read, I should be notified with one week in advance in case of dismissal. But the thing is, my company dismissed me just the 5th of July when probation was ended and notification period expired totally.

What I can do? Can I claim for some compensation or rights? Im working on Gibraltar

Thanks in advice

Comment: Here is not the best place to ask such question and you should seek legal advice from a lawyer.

Comment: Yes I was thinking the same, they pay me 10 days more to compensate. I need to sign the dismiss confirm paper in short term. I will contact with one before, thanks

Comment: Legal advice is off topic, voting to close.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If they're paying you 10 days pay at your dismissal then I'd suggest you've been [paid in lieu of notice](http://acas.org.uk/index.aspx?articleid=4540). That's quite a common clause under UK law, which (I'm assuming) will be similar in Gibraltar, and allows a company to pay you for the time you would have worked during the notice period without having you at work. This may or may not be spelt out in your contract, you should check.

This effectively *is* your compensation - with that payment they've made good on any material loss you'd have otherwise suffered (your wages for the period of time concerned) from them not allowing you to work out your notice period.

Other than that, we can't really offer legal advice here and we haven't seen your contract, so whether or not you might have a case for anything else is impossible to say.

Comment: Yes, they're just going to pay me 10 extra days. Perfect explanation.